# Notepad++ doesnt stpp complaining about changed file

Tags: notepad++

I have Windows 10 64bit here with Notepad++ installed.
I open a file thats written constantly by a program (its indeed a log file).
Now i switch to another program and after a while back to Notepad++.
Notepad++ complains about the changed file with its dialog window.
I accept to reload the file. Now Notepad++ reloads the file (which may take a while). Then normally Notepad++ should have the focus, but it doesnt. So i click on Notepad++. But this triggers the file changed mechanism again.
I don't see how to prevent Notepad++ from loosing focus.

Comment: A work-around I use for logs: open the file in a **browser** and regularly refresh manually (F5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- Menu > Settings > Preferences > MISC

  - Disable Auto-Detection (the file will never been updated whithin Npp)
  - Update silently (the file will be updated without any warnings)

**Caution:** this will act for all files open in Npp.

[image]